# Creating an WordPress blog offline local and hosted later : error surfing the page

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I am planning to create a blog based on WordPress platform. I read some books and blogs about how to use this framework. I found that it's a good practice to install WordPress local and create the blog offline (add a Theme, content, etc. ) and later to order the domain, hosting and make it public.

**Update:** The following error was received while surfing the WordPress page:

> “Error establishing a database connection”.

I tried to resolve the issue but on the wp-admin I get a different error :

> “One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to
>   be repaired”

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question in the current form is not a good fit. SO is for concrete questions. If you have problems getting this to work, please add your non-working code to the question and describe as precisely as possible what does not work and how it fails.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Despite I already know how SO works, because I am an active member and I am specialized in Microsoft Tech like SSAS, SSRS, SSIS and SQL , I am relative new to this topic wich is Wordpress and blogging. I understand the downrated action but the question it's exactly the description for the problem I meet and I couldn't find sufficient infos on web to create in the end an overview. The answer below from @Ajith it's what I am looking for - an advice form an expert in this field regarding the problem that I described.

Comment: Hi, I understand the description fits the problem, but the problem itself is not a good fit for SO, at least in its current form.

Comment: Hi, the question was now updated and rephrased. Now ,because the context was changed entirely, the downrates doesn't refered anymore to the original question. This means that the question was wrong downrated. Please remove the downrates.

Comment: The updates you submitted could have potentially been posted as a new question, as it's a new, and different problem. Even with the current information, it's not a good question. "Error establishing a database connection" — there are thousands of similar (duplicate) questions with the same error message. "I tried to resolve the issue but on the wp-admin I get a different error" — how did you attempt to resolve it?

Comment: logging in to wp-admin

Comment: So from a good asked and good intended question that already received an answer, we have now a duplicate question with two downrates that doesn't match the content and with an answer which also doesn't fit the actual question, because the original question was tend to be ALMOST oponions based and because non-working code was described... How can we solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developing wordpress based websites in past 5 years and usually what I do is, develop entire site on local and move it to the cloud. If you do it public, create a robot file so that search engine can't find you, until you are ready to launch, or good to show others.